# UITextView "Field"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter, uitextview, counter

I would like a text similar to Twitter's

I am currently using a UITextView since it has multi-line support. I kind of figured out how to use a label that counts the characters and keeps the user up to date of any characters added or removed.

Empty:

[image: Empty Field]

With Text:

[image: With Text]

The problem I am having however is when I copy or paste any text in the view, (like if I highlight all the text, as in the second picture) and I delete it, the counter will not update. Or if I paste any text, the count just decrements one character, though the text field limit still stays correct, just the counter is no longer in sync with it.

Code: http://pastebin.com/UK91Ccbb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a delegate method for UITextView as

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
```

it is called every time a character is inserted into the UITextView. In this method set the length of text in your counter UILabel as follows

```
counterlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", textView.text.length];
```

return YES at the end of method if the length is within range i.e. less than or equal to 140 else return NO.

**UPDATE:**..
To restrict to 140 characters.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    return textView.text.length <= 140;

}
```

To handle text removal on selection and counting characters.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (140- textView.text.length)];
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is if I wanted to count. What I want to do is the reverse. Like, I show them the amount they can have, and it's decremented with each typed character and incremented by X when X characters are removed.

Comment: To handle text deletion on selection, simply implement the `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView` method and repeat the above code. For showing remaining characters, do simple math and subtract textView.text.length from 140.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"You added a character");
charactersLeft--;
```

I think the problem here is that you should have written:

```
charactersLeft -= text.length;
```

Comment: Yeah, I got that part. But I'm trying to figure out how to set the character count correctly if I highlight some text and DELETE it instead, since I can't figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad :

```
charactersLeft = 140;
characterCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",charactersLeft];
```

Now use this it works well :

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

NSString *textString = textView.text;
int chars = [textString length];

if (chars <= 140) {
    [characterCountLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(140 - chars)]];
}
}

-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    [textView resignFirstResponder];

if (textView.text.length == 140 && [text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}

else if ((textView.text.length) >= 140 && range.length == 0){

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"You have exceeded the characters limit." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return NO; // return NO to not change text

}

return YES;
```

}

Note that here I have used returnType key to resign the keyboard.You may change it to work as usual.